# Get automatic location in Facebook feed using restfb

Tags: java, facebook, restfb

I'm using RestFB library to interact with Facebook Graph API.
I'm trying to figure out if it's possible, given a photo, a post or anything else, to get the location available which Facebook puts automatically besides the timestamp.
[image]

In the picture, I mean the "Dublino" information in the black rectangle.

Following Graph API documentation, it's possible to specify the Place parameter in the GET req. For this post, it returns "University College Dublin", so the Place where I tagged; in posts where no place tag is explicited, of course it returns null. These info are not what I'm looking for.

Is there any parameter which permits to get the info I need?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`place` has the type `Place` and there you should find the location. In the location you should find the city. And that's what you are looking for.

```
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.6/post
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/place
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/location/
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It works only for post where a place tag is available, doesn't it? In my case there are some posts where place is not tagged but location (as in the blank rectangle) is available. In that case how can I get that information? I think if there's not place tagged, Place object I get is null, so I can't get the location.